# What is the grammatical construction of the clause "Emotions that Maria had thought were buried deep enough ..."

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clauses

> Something in that should have upset Maria, but all she could
> concentrate on was the pain and anguish that ravished her body. It was
> like a silent demon had lay dormant inside of her and fed on all the
> pain that had ever been inflicted on her and those she holds most
> dear. A demon that knew how to bide its time and unleash its festering
> anger on anyone that was responsible for its creation. Was the inner
> demon part of Maria? Or was it separate and just used the woman's body
> as a place to hibernate? Only Maria could answer those questions, and
> she was in no condition to consider them. So many emotions fed that
> silent demon. **Emotions that Maria had thought were buried deep
> enough so they could not betray her at the worst possible moment.**

"Emotions that Maria had thought were buried deep enough so they could not betray her at the worst possible moment."

Is *Emotions* the object of *thought*? But how do you just "think" emotions? It is ungrammatical.

Or perhaps, *that Maria had thought were buried deep enough* is just a relative clause modifying *Emotions*? But this is also ungrammatical, there's no main clause in the sentence now. Is the original sentence grammatically correct in the first place?

Comment: I recall you asked this kind of question before. "Emotions" is not object of "thought" but subject of the embedded _were buried_ clause. We understand "Maria had thought that some emotions were buried deep enough ...". The whole expression in bold is a noun phrase.

Comment: **So many emotions** *that Maria had thought were buried deep enough so they could not betray her at the worst possible moment* **fed that silent demon.** The whole phrase is modifying the subject of the previous sentence, but it's somehow separated by the punctuation. I don't think it's grammatically correct either, but an artistic recourse to make it more poetic.

Comment: @Alberto The whole expression in bold is a noun phrase functioning not as a modifier but as a supplement. It is grammatically correct.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you for the exposition of the grammatical issue mentioned. Do you mean the expression in bold from the quote is not a "sentence"?

Comment: Yes I do. It's not a sentence but a noun phrase centered around the noun "emotions". It expands the meaning of the word "emotions" in the clause that precedes it.

Comment: Ah yes, the old learn-to-read trick: So many **emotions** fed that silent demon; **Emotions** that Maria had thought were buried deep enough so they could not betray her at the worst possible moment. The second phrase is in apposition to the first but is given a literary twist by not being punctuated in a standard manner....{same idea for those who don't get it.] So many questions that boggle the mind. Questions that this poster thought had been overlooked. **The grammar is fine in literary texts.  Appositions are sometimes done that way.**

Answer (score 1):

This question has basically answered in the comments, so I will not explain in detail what has already been said.

The part in bold is indeed not a full sentence. It is an appositive which is normally marked by comma(s), but in literature, peculiar punctuation like this can be used. The apposition is a Noun Phrase consisting of the head ***Emotions*** and the relative ***that Maria had thought were buried deep enough so they could not betray her at the worst possible moment.*** It is this relative that seems to be confusing you.

1. *Emotions* = subject of the verb ***were buried***
2. *that Maria had thought were buried deep enough so they could not betray her at the worst possible moment.* = relative clause, within which:

> - ***[that they]** were buried deep enough* = direct object of *had thought*
> - *so [that] they could not betray her at the worst possible moment* = consecutive adjunct establishing the effect of *were buried deep
>   enough*.

So the object of ***had thought*** is not *emotions* but the object clause *were buried deep enough* which could be replaced by a non-finite infinitive clause:

> Emotions that Maria had thought ***to be buried*** deep enough so they could not betray her at the worst possible moment.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in that sentence. But, sometimes, rephrasing can help understand things better : Maria had thought/considered (that) her emotions were buried so sufficiently deep that they could not betray her at the worst possible moment.

Comment: Actually, it's not technically a sentence.